# Statistics on a booster pack (to make my own re-packs)

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a lot of magic cards.  For constructed play they are mostly worthless.  I would like to pack these up into re-packs that are like booster packs.

But I am not sure what cards go into a booster pack.

NOTE: I am **not** asking about Rareity distribution.  I know that each pack has:

- Token/Advertisement
- Foil/Land
- Rare/Mythic
- 3 (ish) Uncommons
- Rest are Commons

I am asking how random the other types on the cards are.  **Meaning is it possible to open a booster that is all Red?**  or all Creatures?  Or all Sorcery?

**Or is there a guarantee that there will be a certain number of each color, creatures, instants, sorceries, etc.?**

Comment: For what it's worth, if your purpose behind the repacks is to open them to draft with, you should consider building a _cube_ : see http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/multiplayer/11755_The_Cube_20.html , for instance.  (Some people go to the trouble of 'balancing' their cube packs, but many more folks just shuffle up and let randomness be randomness)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no hard guarantee that a booster will contain X creatures, or X sorceries, or X red cards.

However, the contents of a booster aren't completely random either. Instead, the commons in a booster are heavily influenced by the set's *common print runs*.

[Print runs are easiest to explain by example, so let's look at the print runs for Born of the Gods, a small set.](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/limited-sealed-draft/545816-born-of-the-gods-common-print-runs) The commons in the set are divided into two lists, with each common showing up in only one list (but appearing twice in that list).

A normal Born of the Gods booster contains 10 commons, made up of 4–6 commons from list A and 4–6 commons from list B. This means that certain combinations of commons are likely to occur together, and other combinations of commons can never occur together.

Now, all of this is probably too much of a hassle to be worth simulating when building your own repacks. I would probably just add 10 random commons from your pool. But print runs are the basis of how real boosters work, both in paper and online.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it seems as though exact statistics are unavailable, though there are lots of booster/draft simulators available online to help you get a feel for distribution.

The best resource I found for booster pack setup has been [over at MTG salvation](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Booster_pack) and via Wizard's own [Booster Draft Simulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160107051930/http://archive.wizards.com/magic/tcg/resources.aspx?x=mtg/tcg/resources/boosterdraftsimulator).

In general, from playing around with it, it seems as though there will always be at least 2 of each color and half creatures, half other spells.

Unless there is a resource I missed, more details statistics would have to be gathered using some booster simulating system, to which I wish you good luck.

Comment: If they're entirely random, you could probably look at at least several dozen packs without ever seeing fewer than two of a color - I wouldn't infer that it's a rule. And it's definitely not true that they're always half creatures and half noncreature spells. Maybe you meant about half? Which again, is likely to happen with random choices...

Comment: That the statistics are unavailable implies the selection of which commons are placed in a booster isn't random. Could you provide documentation to support that, at least?

Comment: @ikegami Well, they could be fully random and Wizards just hasn't said so, right? (But of course, they can't be *completely* random given that they print the cards in sheets.)

Comment: @Jefromi, Yeah, I suppose that's a possibility too. // Printing cards in sheets of cards containing varied cards (as I presume you meant) doesn't mean it can't be completely random, but if that's what they do, it would imply it's not completely random (because you'd have no reason not to print sheets of identical cards otherwise). Is that what they do? Again, this is the kind of information this answer could use.

Comment: @ikegami They've stated explicitly they print cards in sheets and you can see them if you for example do an image search for "mtg sheet". And I really just meant that they're not *completely* random, because they print some finite number of sheets (presumably equal numbers of each card at a given rarity) and then repackage those into packs, so at the very least they can't *all* be all red, and if they don't mix up all the cards from a really large number of sheets, it's much less random than that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17492/discussion-between-jefromi-and-ikegami).